# How to remove myself as an editor in a GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had joined a GCP project as an editor role long time ago and I'd like to leave it now, but I can't since it says that only project owner role can remove an user. And the project owner is not responding
my request to remove me there.

Is there a way to remove myself?

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove yourself as editor you need the next permission:

`resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy`

I test it in my Google Cloud.

I set the editor role to a colleague, but he is unable to remove the editor role until the `resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy` is added.

Check if you have the role, if you do not have the role is not possible remove by yourself